# Multiple FullCalendars on a single page

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to add multiple FullCalendars (selectable) on same page for scheduling different kinds of events and save information in database but looking the demo/sample code it seems I can add only single calendar per page as it is rendered by the `<div id='calendar'></div>`. Can you plesae let me know if there is way to acheive this, so that when user schedules events on different calendars on same page then calendar source/id can be identified?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392150/is-it-possible-to-display-two-three-months this is what i Found as a link ...seems Okay to me...You can Try..
In here they have used several div(calendars) with single button to control multiple button in each calendar...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the fullcalendar is not rendered simply by `<div id='calendar'></div>`

It is rendered by the `.fullCalendar` call you will make on that div.

```
<div id="calendar"></div>

$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
   // Options
}
```

Is how a FullCalendar is initialized. If you make another div and call it something else, it'll still work.

```
<div id="other-calendar"></div>

$("#other-calendar").fullCalendar({
   // Options
}
```

Since each calendar is created separately, you can define your handlers for each calendar.

Comment: Great, I'm doing the same thing. Is there a way to share the buttons? I'd like it to skip the week for all calendars when I click next.