# jquery fullcalendar plugin view more then 1 month at a time

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using the fullcalendar plugin and would like to change it a little bit - I want the default to be month view , but able to scroll down and continue into the next month, does anyone know if there is an add on , or anyway to start going about editing the fullcalendar?

Comment: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ shows me month view by default. what do u mean by scroll down? you want a scrollbar so you can scroll down to see next month?

Comment: This question is a few months old , I have found out what I wanted to do is not possible- I wanted the month view, but if you scroll down past the last row in the month , then then next row is starting the next month, and that continues based on scrolling to fecth more data from db and you can keep going down for the next 6 months @AamirAfridi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way in fullcalendar to show two months. for your requirement you need to merge fullcalnder with darepicker ahow one small datepicker above the fullcaleder and one click of datepicker call goto methode of fullcalendar to jump at requried date.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{     
    $("#datepicker" ).datepicker({

        numberOfMonths: 2,
        showButtonPanel: false,
        minDate:0,

        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) 
        {  
            selected_date = dateText;
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate',new Date(Date.parse(selected_date)));
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish as follows:

1. Download the data and save the JSON in local storage or an array
2. Create 2-3 divs for 2-3 calendars
3. Load full calendar onto the divs-- setting the start date for each
4. Keep the same data source for all

Like this:

[Multiple FullCalendars on a single page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392162/multiple-fullcalendars-on-a-single-page)

with options

Comment: this project was done a long time ago, but that is actually a really good idea, thanks