# Php+Jquery+Ajax+Date Range Selector calendar with two months a page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, fullcalendar

I'm working on a car rental website. In this site I need to show a availability calendar where I need to show the available, unavailable and booked days. For this I want a calendar to which have date range selector to allow users to book for more than on day. Apart from this also want to show only two months a page, the current month and the next month with a button to show the rest of the months incrementing by two months.

What I've tried the followings :

1) I've used FullCalendar with -> selectable: true,
2) Set month view to default view
3) Used ajax to book

My Issue is :

1) Fullcalendar does not allow to display two months

To overcome this I've tried this hack :

[Multiple FullCalendars on a single page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392162/multiple-fullcalendars-on-a-single-page)

But this is also not fullfilling my needs. This does not allow me to drag dates to the other calendar. Also no option to vie the comming months. Please help.

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: You need to create a custom view or modify existing view using [custom view](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/)